# Dart - When To Use Collection-For-In vs .Map() on Collections

Tags: dart, collections, for-in-loop

Both the collection-for-in operation and .map() method can return some manipulation of elements from a previous collection. Is there ever any reason to prefer using one over the other?

```dart
var myList = [1,2,3];
var alteredList1 = [for(int i in myList) i + 2]; //[3,4,5]
var alteredList2 = myList.map((e) => e + 2).toList(); //[3,4,5]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use whichever is easier and more readable.
That's a deliberately vague answer, because it depends on what you are doing.

Any time you have something ending in `.toList()` I'd at least *consider* making it into a list literal. If the body of the `map` or `where` is simple, you can usually rewrite it directly to a list literal using `for`/`in` (plus `if` for `where`).
And then, sometimes it gets complicated, you need to use the same variable twice, or the `map` computation uses a `while` loop, or something else doesn't just fit into the list literal syntax.

Then you can either keep the helper function and do `[for (var e in something) helperFunction(e)]` or just do `something.map((e) { body of helper function }).toList()`. In many cases the latter is then more readable.

So, consider using a list literal if your iterable code ends in `toList`, but if the literal gets too convoluted, don't feel bad about using the `.map(...).toList()` approach.

Readability is all that really matters.

Comment: In the case where readability is mostly equal, or in cases where we want to squeeze each last drop of performance, is there any difference?

I feel like the literal will be marginally more performant than `.map`, although I prefer `.map` myself.

Comment: When it comes to performance of a modern, optimizing, possibly-jit-compiled and garbage collected language, the only way to be sure is to measure.
I'd also expect the literals to be slightly more performant, but if a JIT recognizes and optimizes the crap out of `.map(...).toList()`, it could very well be as fast.

Answer (score 2):

Not an expert but personally I prefer the first method. Some reasons:

1. You can include other elements (independent from the for loop) in the same list:

   ```dart
   var a = [1, 2, 3];
   bool include5 = true;
   var b = [
     1,
     for (var i in a) i + 1,
     if (include5) 5,
   ];
   print(b); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
   ```
2. Sometimes when mapping models to a list of Widgets the `.map().toList()` method will produce a `List<dynamic>`, implicit casting won't work. When you come across such an error just avoid the second method.