# flutter _TypeError (type '(dynamic) => Categorys' is not a subtype of type '(String, dynamic) => MapEntry<dynamic, dynamic>' of 'transform')

Tags: flutter

**i am using getx pluign i am facing problem _TypeError (type '(dynamic) => Categorys' is not a subtype of type '(String, dynamic) => MapEntry<dynamic, dynamic>' of 'transform')
**

**my model**

```js
// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final categorys = categorysFromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:get/get_rx/src/rx_types/rx_types.dart';
// ignore: non_constant_identifier_names

// ignore: non_constant_identifier_names

// ignore: non_constant_identifier_names
List CategorysFromJson(dynamic str) =>
    List<Categorys>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => Categorys.fromJson(x)));

// ignore: non_constant_identifier_names
String CategorysToJson(List<Categorys> data) =>
    json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));
var isFavorite = false.obs;

class Categorys {
  Categorys({
    required this.data,
  });

  List<Datum> data;

  factory Categorys.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Categorys(
        data: List<Datum>.from(json["data"].map((x) => Datum.fromJson(x))),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "data": List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())),
      };
}

class Datum {
  Datum({
    required this.id,
    required this.title,
    required this.details,
    required this.createdAt,
    required this.updatedAt,
    required this.image,
    required this.media,
  });

  int id;
  String title;
  String details;
  DateTime createdAt;
  DateTime updatedAt;
  List<Image> image;
  List<Image> media;

  factory Datum.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Datum(
        id: json["id"],
        title: json["title"],
        details: json["details"],
        createdAt: DateTime.parse(json["created_at"]),
        updatedAt: DateTime.parse(json["updated_at"]),
        image: List<Image>.from(json["image"].map((x) => Image.fromJson(x))),
        media: List<Image>.from(json["media"].map((x) => Image.fromJson(x))),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "title": title,
        "details": details,
        "created_at": createdAt.toIso8601String(),
        "updated_at": updatedAt.toIso8601String(),
        "image": List<dynamic>.from(image.map((x) => x.toJson())),
        "media": List<dynamic>.from(media.map((x) => x.toJson())),
      };
}

class Image {
  Image({
    required this.id,
    required this.modelType,
    required this.modelId,
    required this.uuid,
    required this.collectionName,
    required this.name,
    required this.fileName,
    required this.mimeType,
    required this.disk,
    required this.conversionsDisk,
    required this.size,
    required this.manipulations,
    required this.customProperties,
    required this.responsiveImages,
    required this.orderColumn,
    required this.createdAt,
    required this.updatedAt,
    required this.url,
    required this.thumbnail,
    required this.previewThumbnail,
  });

  int id;
  String modelType;
  int modelId;
  String uuid;
  String collectionName;
  String name;
  String fileName;
  String mimeType;
  String disk;
  String conversionsDisk;
  int size;
  List<dynamic> manipulations;
  CustomProperties customProperties;
  List<dynamic> responsiveImages;
  int orderColumn;
  DateTime createdAt;
  DateTime updatedAt;
  String url;
  String thumbnail;
  String previewThumbnail;

  factory Image.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Image(
        id: json["id"],
        modelType: json["model_type"],
        modelId: json["model_id"],
        uuid: json["uuid"],
        collectionName: json["collection_name"],
        name: json["name"],
        fileName: json["file_name"],
        mimeType: json["mime_type"],
        disk: json["disk"],
        conversionsDisk: json["conversions_disk"],
        size: json["size"],
        manipulations: List<dynamic>.from(json["manipulations"].map((x) => x)),
        customProperties: CustomProperties.fromJson(json["custom_properties"]),
        responsiveImages:
            List<dynamic>.from(json["responsive_images"].map((x) => x)),
        orderColumn: json["order_column"],
        createdAt: DateTime.parse(json["created_at"]),
        updatedAt: DateTime.parse(json["updated_at"]),
        url: json["url"] == null ? null : json["url"],
        thumbnail: json["thumbnail"] == null ? null : json["thumbnail"],
        previewThumbnail: json["preview_thumbnail"] == null
            ? null
            : json["preview_thumbnail"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "model_type": modelType,
        "model_id": modelId,
        "uuid": uuid,
        "collection_name": collectionName,
        "name": name,
        "file_name": fileName,
        "mime_type": mimeType,
        "disk": disk,
        "conversions_disk": conversionsDisk,
        "size": size,
        "manipulations": List<dynamic>.from(manipulations.map((x) => x)),
        "custom_properties": customProperties.toJson(),
        "responsive_images": List<dynamic>.from(responsiveImages.map((x) => x)),
        "order_column": orderColumn,
        "created_at": createdAt.toIso8601String(),
        "updated_at": updatedAt.toIso8601String(),
        "url": url == null ? null : url,
        "thumbnail": thumbnail == null ? null : thumbnail,
        "preview_thumbnail": previewThumbnail == null ? null : previewThumbnail,
      };
}

class CustomProperties {
  CustomProperties({
    required this.generatedConversions,
  });

  GeneratedConversions generatedConversions;

  factory CustomProperties.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      CustomProperties(
        generatedConversions:
            GeneratedConversions.fromJson(json["generated_conversions"]),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "generated_conversions": generatedConversions.toJson(),
      };
}

class GeneratedConversions {
  GeneratedConversions({
    required this.thumbnail,
    required this.previewThumbnail,
  });

  bool thumbnail;
  bool previewThumbnail;

  factory GeneratedConversions.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      GeneratedConversions(
        thumbnail: json["thumbnail"],
        previewThumbnail: json["preview_thumbnail"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "thumbnail": thumbnail,
        "preview_thumbnail": previewThumbnail,
      };
}
```

**my services**

```js
class CategoryServices {
  static var client = http.Client();

  static Future<List?> fetchCategorys() async {
    var response = await client
        .get(Uri.parse('http://localhost/api/users/get_plancategory'));
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var jsonString = response.body;
      print(jsonString);
      return CategorysFromJson(jsonString);
    } else {
      //show error message
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

**my controller**

```js
class CategoryController extends GetxController {
  var isLoading = true.obs;
  var categorysList = <Categorys>[].obs;

  @override
  void onInit() {
    fetchCategorys();
    super.onInit();
  }

  void fetchCategorys() async {
    try {
      isLoading(true);
      var categorys = await CategoryServices.fetchCategorys();

      if (categorys != null) {
        categorysList.value = categorys as List<Categorys>;
      }
    } finally {
      isLoading(false);
    }
  }
}
```

**api response

```js
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "test",
            "details": "test details",
            "created_at": "2022-01-28 08:12:19",
            "updated_at": "2022-01-28 08:12:19",
            "image": [
                {
                    "id": 10,
                    "model_type": "App\\Models\\PalnCategory",
                    "model_id": 1,
                    "uuid": "d6623251-b0fc-404d-9071-530074e7d181",
                    "collection_name": "paln_category_image",
                    "name": "img1",
                    "file_name": "img1.png",
                    "mime_type": "image/png",
                    "disk": "public",
                    "conversions_disk": "public",
                    "size": 293049,
                    "manipulations": [],
                    "custom_properties": {
                        "generated_conversions": {
                            "thumbnail": true,
                            "preview_thumbnail": true
                        }
                    },
                    "responsive_images": [],
                    "order_column": 4,
                    "created_at": "2022-01-28T08:12:09.000000Z",
                    "updated_at": "2022-01-28T08:12:19.000000Z",
                    "url": "http://localhost/storage/10/img1.png",
                    "thumbnail": "http://localhost/storage/10/conversions/img1-thumbnail.jpg",
                    "preview_thumbnail": "http://localhost/storage/10/conversions/img1-preview_thumbnail.jpg"
                }
            ],
            "media": [
                {
                    "id": 10,
                    "model_type": "App\\Models\\PalnCategory",
                    "model_id": 1,
                    "uuid": "d6623251-b0fc-404d-9071-530074e7d181",
                    "collection_name": "paln_category_image",
                    "name": "img1",
                    "file_name": "img1.png",
                    "mime_type": "image/png",
                    "disk": "public",
                    "conversions_disk": "public",
                    "size": 293049,
                    "manipulations": [],
                    "custom_properties": {
                        "generated_conversions": {
                            "thumbnail": true,
                            "preview_thumbnail": true
                        }
                    },
                    "responsive_images": [],
                    "order_column": 4,
                    "created_at": "2022-01-28T08:12:09.000000Z",
                    "updated_at": "2022-01-28T08:12:19.000000Z"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "title": "test2",
            "details": "test2 details",
            "created_at": "2022-01-28 08:12:38",
            "updated_at": "2022-01-28 08:12:38",
            "image": [
                {
                    "id": 11,
                    "model_type": "App\\Models\\PalnCategory",
                    "model_id": 2,
                    "uuid": "7bb9e303-8b1c-4672-8ddb-981e2ab3c895",
                    "collection_name": "paln_category_image",
                    "name": "img2",
                    "file_name": "img2.png",
                    "mime_type": "image/png",
                    "disk": "public",
                    "conversions_disk": "public",
                    "size": 236448,
                    "manipulations": [],
                    "custom_properties": {
                        "generated_conversions": {
                            "thumbnail": true,
                            "preview_thumbnail": true
                        }
                    },
                    "responsive_images": [],
                    "order_column": 5,
                    "created_at": "2022-01-28T08:12:32.000000Z",
                    "updated_at": "2022-01-28T08:12:38.000000Z",
                    "url": "http://localhost/storage/11/img2.png",
                    "thumbnail": "http://localhost/storage/11/conversions/img2-thumbnail.jpg",
                    "preview_thumbnail": "http://localhost/storage/11/conversions/img2-preview_thumbnail.jpg"
                }
            ],
            "media": [
                {
                    "id": 11,
                    "model_type": "App\\Models\\PalnCategory",
                    "model_id": 2,
                    "uuid": "7bb9e303-8b1c-4672-8ddb-981e2ab3c895",
                    "collection_name": "paln_category_image",
                    "name": "img2",
                    "file_name": "img2.png",
                    "mime_type": "image/png",
                    "disk": "public",
                    "conversions_disk": "public",
                    "size": 236448,
                    "manipulations": [],
                    "custom_properties": {
                        "generated_conversions": {
                            "thumbnail": true,
                            "preview_thumbnail": true
                        }
                    },
                    "responsive_images": [],
                    "order_column": 5,
                    "created_at": "2022-01-28T08:12:32.000000Z",
                    "updated_at": "2022-01-28T08:12:38.000000Z"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**
**i am using getx pluign i am facing problem _TypeError (type '(dynamic) => Categorys' is not a subtype of type '(String, dynamic) => MapEntry<dynamic, dynamic>' of 'transform')

```
List<Categorys>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => Categorys.fromJson(x)));
```

this line show error
**

Answer (score 0):

Check this [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69380368/14502033):

tldr; Use a for-in generator instead of `.map()` as casting does not work for some reason uknown to me.

Replace

```dart
List<Categorys>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => Categorys.fromJson(x)));
```

with

```dart
[
  for (Map<String, dynamic> x in json.decode(str)) Categorys.fromJson(x),
] as List<Categorys>;
```

Also may I suggest that you change `Categorys` to `Categories` :)

Comment: A list literal can't be prefixed by 'List'.
Try removing 'List'dart

Comment: @vignesh changed it.

Comment: i am trying but error Object x
The argument type 'Object' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String, dynamic>'.

Comment: List<Categorys>.from([
      for (Object x in json.decode(str))
        Categorys.fromJson(x as Map<String, dynamic>),
    ].toList());                                                                                                                                                                    the x value null and error show Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable<dynamic>'

Comment: @vignesh The error is pretty self explanatory. x should be a Map<String, dynamic>... so instead of Object x it should be Map<String, dynamic> x

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
List.from(json.decode(str)).map((x) => Categorys.fromJson(Map.from(x)))).toList();
```

Comment: _TypeError (type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable<dynamic>')

Comment: Hey, @vignesh, I've updated my answer, try again.